# How could I return a dialog and use intent too?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, dialog

Using android studio with java, I am using a `dialog` class called `ExampleDialog.java` ran from `MainActivity.java`. I have to pass one `int` and one `String` to `MainActivity.java`.

I tried to use intent to pass the values, but there is a problem when there are consecutive `return dialog;` and `startActivity(intent);`.

I tried to remove first the `return dialog;` and keep the `startActivity(intent);` but it does not work well because there are problems with the dialog.

I also tried the opposite by removing the `startActivity(intent);` and keeping the `return dialog;`. In this case, I think that the `int` and the `String` are not passed to `MainActivity.java`, so this does not work too.

**ExampleDialog.java:**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//code

   Dialog dialog = builder.create();Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NAME", name);
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NUMBER", number);

   startActivity(intent);
   return dialog ;

}
```

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#PassingEvents

Comment: The question is not clear, can you explain more clearly?

Comment: Basically the `return dialog;` and the `startActivity(intent);` are in conflict, and I was asking if there is a way to ensure that they can fit together. The first user who commented the post suggested an AlertDialog, I will try today. @Khemraj